# Swift How to make animation that is similar to iOS App Launch animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working a huge secret project which is replica of iOS GUI, and I want to make a animation which occurs when we open app in home screen of iOS.

I'm making app with Swift Language. 
If you Press a button for example, Message icon,Message ViewController show up with iOS Animation(Zoome in and Zoom out to icon)

Comment: If you want an answer tell us less about your secrets and more about your needs.  Try simply describing what the animation needs to do.

Comment: If you Press a button for example, Message icon,Message ViewController show up with iOS Animation(Zoome in and Zoom out to icon) @CandiedOrange

Comment: Try putting details like that prominently in your question.  Don't bury them down in the comments.

Comment: @CandiedOrange It's up there.

Comment: Great, now try removing the unneeded noise.  Appreciation and thank you's in the question are not needed or appreciated.  Same for "Can you help me?".  The start could simply be, "I'm making a replica of the iOS gui".

Comment: Check this: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/zoomingviewcontroller-to-animate-uiview.html

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Hi, Can you please give me example that has Swift Language?

Comment: That is what you exactly need?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes. Swift Language please.

Comment: Ok I will make example project with swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83163/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-joonwoo-kim).

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Can you please tell me how to open custom UIViewController please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete example code for Zoom in and Zoom out animation:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleImage: UIImageView!
    var isFullScreen = Bool()
    var prevFrame = CGRect()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        isFullScreen = false

        // add tap gesture into your image
        var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
        sampleImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func imageTapped(img: AnyObject){

        //Code for zoom in and zoom out animation
        if !isFullScreen {

            UIView.animateWithDuration (0.5, delay: 0.0, options: nil ,animations: {
                self.prevFrame = self.sampleImage.frame
                self.sampleImage.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.isFullScreen = true
            })
        } else {

            UIView.animateWithDuration (0.5, delay: 0.0, options: nil ,animations: {
                self.sampleImage.frame = self.prevFrame
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.isFullScreen = false
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention into comment why down vote my answer.

Comment: Hi, can you please also tell me how to open custom view controller in UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds? such as             let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("camera")
            self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)